Would it be appropriate to edit this question?
Referring to this question yesterday:
Do compound eyes exist in nature that have multiple "pixels" per ommatidium?
The text of the question is:

If yes, which species? What is the terminology for such eyes?

Naturally, the comments request evidence of prior research.
The user proceeded to post that research in the form of an answer to the question. This didn't in itself provide a definitive answer, but was good background. They were encouraged to edit the question inserting the images etc. there rather than in an answer.
As of this question, it's only been 15 hours since the user last responded but it occurs to me to edit the contents of the answer into the question and flag the answer for deletion.
My questions: Would it be appropriate to do this? If so, when? (I.e. how long should I give the user to do it themselves before pitching-in)

I generally give OP a couple of days to respond. Giving a nudge by commenting on the post is a great way to help OP improve the Q. Subsequently, downvoting the question is a logical next step; the Q is underresearched and this would personally be my next step now I have commented on the post. Then, gross edits and/or putting the Q on hold comes to mind indeed.

This particular question has other faults. 1. It does not include the question in the body of the text but only in the title. 2. It uses the term "pixel" which is not an anatomical term and requires clarifying. I appreciate that non-native English speakers prefer to keep questions short, but this is inadequate.

I generally give OP a couple of days to respond before taking bigger steps.
I often operate by the following sequence (barred the issue is big enough to keep track of the question, because of user flags):

First start by giving OP a nudge by commenting on the post. This is a great way to help OP improve the Q.
Downvoting the question after commenting is a logical next step; the Q is underresearched and this would personally be my next step now I have commented on the post.
Then, gross edits come to mind.
And finally, when the issue is big enough, the Q can be flagged for mod attention, or you can vote to put the Q on hold.

